# End line StringBuilder in RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, string, java-io, randomaccessfile

I'm trying use the class RandomAccessFile, but I have a problem with the Strings.

This is the first part. Write in a File:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("/home/pep/java/randomFile.dat");
    RandomAccessFile fitxerAleatori = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

    String[] surnames = { "SMITH", 
            "LOMU" };
    int[] dep = { 10,
            20 };
    Double[] salary = { 1200.50, 
            1200.50 };

    StringBuilder buffer = null;
    int n = surnames.length;

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        randomFile.writeInt(i+1); //ID
        buffer = new StringBuilder(surnames[i]);
        buffer.setLength(10); //10 characters
        randomFile.writeChars(buffer.toString());
        randomFile.writeInt(dep[i]);
        randomFile.writeDouble(salary[i]);
    }
    randomFile.close();
}
```

In the second part, I try read this file:

```
    File file = new File("/home/pep/java/randomFile.dat");
    RandomAccessFile randomFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

    char[] surname = new char[10];
    char aux;
    int id, dep, pos;
    Double salary;

    pos = 0;

    for (;;) {
        randomFile.seek(pos);
        id = randomFile.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < surname.length; i++) {
            aux = randomFile.readChar();
            surname[i] = aux;
        }
        String surnameStr = new String(surname); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!
        dep = randomFile.readInt();
        salary = randomFile.readDouble();
        System.out.println("ID: " + id + ", Surname: " + surnameStr + ", Departament: " + dep + ", Salary: " + salary);

        pos = pos + 36; // 4 + 20 + 4 + 8

        if (randomFile.getFilePointer() == randomFile.length())
            break;
    }
    randomFile.close();
}
```

Well, when I hope read:

> ID: 1, Surname: SMITH, Dep: 10, Salary: 1200.50

I recived:

> ID: 1, Surname: SMITH

It's like in the surname there is a end of line, because if I don't display the surname, the other info is correct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the char array. I change de loop for that read the chars:

```
for (int i = 0; i < surname.length; i++) {
            aux = randomFile.readChar();
            surname[i] = aux != 0 ? aux : ' ';
        }
```

Comment: The problem is in the data itself. You haven't agreed with yourself about how to treat string shorter than ten characters.

Answer (score 1):

Where does `cognom` come from? [Edit: OK, I found it. It's Catalan for *surname*. And now the typo coming from *departamento* is also clear. :-]

What do you get if you insert `System.out.println( Arrays.toString( surname ))` before the problem line? I assume it's something like [S, M, I, T, H, [], [], [], [], []] (in Eclipse's Console view). Where `[]` stands for a square, i.e. a non-printable character.

What do you get if you insert `System.out.println( (int) surname[5] )`? I assume it's 0. And I assume this 0 value is causing the problem.

What do you get if you use a surname that's exactly 10 characters long?

Hint 1: There's a typo in `Departament`.

Hint 2: Give `System.out.printf(...)` a chance in favour of `println(...)`.

Hint 3: The `if` in your solution can be shortened to the more elegant:

```
    cognom[i] = aux != 0 ? aux : ' ';
```

Comment: System.out.println( Arrays.toString( surname ));-->[S, M, I, T, H,

Comment: System.out.println( (int) surname[5] )--> 0

Comment: exactly 10 characters long p.e. (SMITHSMITH) --> OK. It shows all the data: ID: 1, Surname: SMITHSMITH, Departament: 10, Salary: 1200.5

Comment: You are right with the 0 value was causing the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a StringBuffer and setting its length to ten will cause nulls to be written for strings shorter than ten characters, and that in turn will cause a decoding problem when you read. It would be much better to create a String, pad it with *spaces* to ten chars, write it, then trim() the resulting String when you read it.